# Asana redirects properly in Safari but not google chrome

Tags: asana

So currently I have an application that has a main web page (ex. www.mainpage.com) and a route where all of my asana work will be done. (ex. www.mainpage.com/myroute).

In myroute, when the page is first loaded I attempt to get get authorization using Oauth (I am using node asana library). Currently I am just testing to see if the app can get authorized and then pull my personal info from asana.

The problem is that everything seems to work fine in Safari. However, in google chrome every time my application becomes authorized, it goes back to www.mainpage.com even though I have set the redirectURL to be www.mainpage.com/myroute

Does anyone have an idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually have no idea about what's actually happening internally, but apparently when you create a route using angular-fullstack it creates an object which sort of declares the main controller that will be used for the route.

However, when I was editing my HTML page I created a div tag with the ng-controller attribute set. Apparently you can only have the "declaration" in one place. In other words, keep the controller in the object that angular-fullstack generates or keep the ng-controller tag in your html, but do not use both.

If anyone can explain the details of how that actually causes methods within the controller to fire twice or why it would reroute the application to the main page, It'd be very appreciated.